# How does Hagrid travel?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid

Hagrid is seen all over the country throughout the series. Normal wizards travel by apparating, floo powder, brooms, and (occasionally) muggle transportation.

Hagrid appears to big to use the floo network, he can't ride a broom, and cannot legally apparate. So how does he get to London from Hogwarts which is located in Scotland?

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7712/4918 "How did Hagrid get to the old house on the rock?"

Comment: He always carries his wand/umbrella with him, so I'd like to think he travels Marry Poppins style.  =)

Comment: @Kai - I know it may get downvoted if you post it but THAT should have been an answer. Awesome :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only transportation Hagrid is ever shown to use in canon are:

- Sirius' flying motorbike (in *PS* when he delivers baby Harry to Privet drive, and *DH* during Battle of Seven Potters);
- Muggle subway in *PS* when he takes Harry to Diagon Alley. However, that was a new experience for him: `Although Hagrid seemed to know where he was going, he was obviously not used to getting there in an ordinary way`.

However, we can add to your list the following possibilities:

- a possibility of MoM **portkeys** - while it's not detailed in book canon, my impression from Pottermore is that portkeys are definitely used for travel to preset destinations (and if the MoM would schedule portkeys available to the public, it'd be to London where MoM is).
- Knight Bus

  Finally found a quote proving that!

  > 'Buckbeak's case against the Committee fer the Disposal o' Dangerous Creatures,' said Hagrid. 'This Friday. **Him an' me'll be goin' down ter London together. I've booked two beds on the Knight Bus**...' (*PoA, Chapter 14, "Snape's Grudge"*)
- Apparently, he flies to places - it's **unspecified how**, but presumably said-same Sirius's motorbike (except, where was the motorbike when he and Harry were leaving? No clue)

  > "How did you get here?" Harry asked, looking around for another boat.
  >   "Flew," said Hagrid.
  >   "Flew?"
  >   "Yeah -- but we'll go back in this. Not s'pposed ter use magic now I've
  >   got yeh."
  >   They settled down in the boat, Harry still staring at Hagrid, trying to
  >   imagine him flying.
  >   (*PS*)
- While I seriously doubt Hagrid could fly a Thestral {{update: as per @MacCooper, he said explicitly the weight was too much in *DH*: `We'll be on the bike, brooms an' thestrals can't take me weight, see` }} - or even try riding several, he'd be concerned for the animal's well-being - he could likely ride an Abraxan non-invisible winged horse, at least when/where Muggles can't see him.

  > 'Yeah, tha's right. Over . . . over a friend's broomstick. I don' fly, meself. Well, look at the size o' me, I don' reckon there's a broomstick that'd hold me. Friend o' mine breeds Abraxan horses, I dunno if you've ever seen 'em, big beasts, winged, yeh know, I've had a bit of a ride on one o' them an' it was ' (*OotP, reply to Umbridge*)
- In addition, while you stated that Hagris is too big to use Floo network, I'm not entirely certain that this is canonically proven. While it MAY be true, it MAY also be that wizarding fireplaces connected to Floo are enchanted to magically enlarge if a large party (of several people, OR a half-giant) show up. This is pure speculation, I don't think we know one way or the other from canon.

Comment: dont forget he can fly in book 1 before g̶o̶d̶JKR remembers that only voldemort can fly.

Comment: There were thirty seconds in that, DVK. 30 damn seconds.

Comment: @MacCooper - sorry 'bout that. And himarm - I was fetching the supporting quote JUST for that :)

Comment: It is possible that by sentence "I flew of course" he meant that he was flying a Hippogriff, used portkey or maybe Fawkes. He also might used multiple Thestrals to get to the island and Harry just couldn't see them yet :)

Comment: @VanjaVasiljevic - i am pretty sure he'd NOT abuse a Thestral this way! :)  But a Hyppogrif... possible, not sure it would supoprt Hagrid's size. Wasn't a Portkey for sure with Harry - or else, he'd have simply had portkey for getting back, no magic needed to be user.

Comment: No, it's what I deserve for taking my eye of the ball (for thirty seconds :DD) @VanjaVasiljevic wouldn't he be unable to ride hippogriffs? they're basically horses with wings, like thestrals, and he's too big for them. edit: OMG DVK 19 seconds! I quit ;)

Comment: @MacCooper - Nobody *deserves* to be late to the **surprise** party. Also, my answer's not nearly as comprehensive as can be, so you can easily beat me on quality.

Comment: still he can use Fawkes since Phoenixes can pull very large weight . But many Thestrals or Hippogriffs is not so unbelivable, he does have whole herd of it :D

Comment: @DVK, in all seriousness, my answer -- you can see it right? 10k rep? -- is crap. I have 0 canon to back it up and haven't the will to find quotes for such a weak answer. If i had twitter, I'd just ask JK and trump you all with word of God, but alas. But DVK, for your last paragraph -- Deathly Hallows, The Seven Potters, Hagrid says the Thestrals cannot take his weight -- there's a quote for ya :)

Comment: @VanjaVasiljevic - I have the same objection as far as Fawkes - if he could have permission from Dumbledore to use him, he'd have used him to fetch Harry to London as well.

Comment: @MacCooper - yes, that was the bases for my rejection of thestrals, good catch!

Comment: Didn't he fly Buckbeak?

Comment: @Oak, I don't believe so. I think only Hermione, Harry and Sirius do.

Comment: I added the quote, but the formatting's fudged and I dont wanna mess it up more than I already have ^^ cant seem to get it into a box quote. I know how, but it;s not cooperating :D

Comment: @MacCooper- awsome, thanks. I made a different formatting, just to avoid the fight with Markdown :)

Comment: @Himarm How did you do a strikethrough in a comment??? I need to know! :-P

Comment: @randal'thor - **maybe** this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154788/why-are-comments-overlapping-the-sidebar/154791#154791

Comment: Was the second quote from a book verbatim? I seem to recall taking it as [flue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flue) when I heard that in the movie.

Answer (score 1):

He uses magic :D

Now seriously,
He might still use [Sirius' flying motorcycle](http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20101111223700/harrypotter/images/2/22/Motorbike.jpg) since it is shown that he has it in Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone and and Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows.

Also he uses magic to enhance normal muggle vehicles like speed up boat in Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone.

He can also use [Knight Bus](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Knight_Bus).

Not to mention that there is a possibility of  flying a Hippogriff, using a portkey or even Fawkes. He also might used multiple Thestrals to support his weight.